# making deserialised class more robust

Tags: c#

I use this:

[http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/][1]

to create some classes from some XML. Sometimes the translation suggests:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName="sup")]
public List<string> Sup { get; set; }
```

and sometimes:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "sup")]
public Sup Sup { get; set; } }
```

Can I make my deserialisation class more robust to cope with both situations?

PS:

Using this:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName= "sub")]
public List<Sub> Sub { get; set; }
[XmlElement(ElementName = "sup")]
public List<Sup> Sup { get; set; }
```

made everything more robust

Comment: I do not think so.  I think the parents of the two object are different so you need tow different class names.

Comment: Thanks but how do I handle this as both 'types' of xml could be send?

Comment: a list can contain 0, 1 or more objects, you should probably try something like `public List<sup> Sup { get; set; }`

Comment: without seeing the entire xml structure I can't answer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this I have created Example for you this both XML will be handled with my given model

Simply Use Parent of all That is **List of the object**
if we are getting string still it will take and if the list of strings then also and same for an object if its single object or multiple All problem will be solved I guess

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Hello</heading>
<heading>Hello2</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>





<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading><subhead>Data</subhead></heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>




    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "note")]
    public class Note
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "to")]
        public string To { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "from")]
        public string From { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "heading")]
        public List<object> Heading { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

Whole Tested Example:-

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText("D://pleasecheckXML.txt");
            XmlSerializer xmldata = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Note));
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            var datafromxml = xmldata.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "note")]
    public class Note
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "to")]
        public string To { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "from")]
        public string From { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "heading")]
        public List<object> Heading { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

}
```